# Problems replacing a substring

Tags: r, string, replace

Let the string **s** be

```
structure(",SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(CG_PART,((CG_PART[0NIVEL4] = \"4.03.01.003\"))  && CG_PART[isEstorno] = 0 ) ,\"Data\",CG_PART[DATA], \"D/C\", CG_PART[D_C],\"Nivel1\", \"(-) Custo de serviços\", \"Nivel2\", \"Custo de Frete de Serviços PJ\",\"Nivel3\", [0NIVEL4],\"Valor\", IF(CG_PART[D_C] = \"D\",-CG_PART[VALORR],CG_PART[VALORR]), \"Ordem Apresentacao\", 7, \"isSub\", 0)")
```

I would like to replace the content:

```
\"Nivel1\", \"(-) Custo de serviços\", \"Nivel2\", \"Custo de Frete de
Serviços PJ\",\"Nivel3\", [0NIVEL4],\"Valor\"
```

to this one:

```
\"Nivel1\", \"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\",\"Nivel2\", \"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL 
LÍQUIDA\", \"Nivel3\",\"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\",\"Valor\"
```

so I've used this code

```
init.pos <- str_start(s, "\"Nivel1\"",ignore.case = F)
end.pos <- str_end(s, ",\"Valor\"",ignore.case = F)  

substr(s, init.pos, end.pos) <- "\"Nivel1\",  \"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\",\"Nivel2\", \"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\", \"Nivel3\",\"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\", \"Valor\""
```

The problem arises when my sub-string is getting replaced wrongly. It appears that the string used to replace is getting cut in the middle.

Then added in my code this logic:

```
middle.pos <- (init.pos+end.pos)/2
substr(s, middle.pos, end.pos) <- "\"Nivel3\",\"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\", \"Valor\""
substr(s, init.pos, middle.pos-1) <- "\"Nivel1\",  \"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\",\"Nivel2\", \"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\","
```

And it got some weird output. I would your help to understand why is this happening.

---

OBS: The reason why I've used this logic is because I will run my code to replace the content between "Nivel1" and "Valor" with a new content, but the strings between them vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gsub](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/grep) to replace the content between "Nivel1" and "Valor" with a new content.

```
tt <- "\"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\",\"Nivel2\", \"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\", \"Nivel3\",\"(=) RECEITA OPERACIONAL LÍQUIDA\","

gsub("(.*\"Nivel1\").*(\"Valor\".*)", paste("\\1", tt, "\\2"), s, ignore.case = FALSE)
```